# If picking a 12-bit string uniformly at random, what is the probability that the string has more than one 0 and more than one 1?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am kinda stumped on this question. I am not completely sure on where to start. Any pointers appreciated.

I have tried to calculate the strings only containing one 1 and the strings containing one 0 and zero 1s and zero 0s and use the cardinality of this divided by the total number of strings, but I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: You are correct. The only thing you are missing is that you want the opposite of that. You want the total number of strings minus the number of cases with one or fewer $0$s or one or fewer $1$s all divided by the total number of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is problem where its easier to calculate the complement.

If we let $P =$ probability that the string has more than one 0 and more than one 1.

Then $1 -P =$ probability that the string has zero or one 0's and zero and or one 1's.

There are zero 0's or zero 1's when the string is either all 0's or all 1's.

There are twelve string's with one 0 (011111111111, 101111111111,..., 111111111110). Simillary, there are twelve string's with one 1.

So there are a total of 26 strings satifying the $1-P$ description. There are $2^{12}$ possible strings, so $1-P = \frac{26}{2^{12}} = \frac{13}{2^{11}}$, so $P = 1 - \frac{13}{2^{11}}$.